# Is it best practice to keep settings in root web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have hundreds of sub-web.configs who have same app settings so I was wondering if it's alright to merge them all and put them into root web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're the developer, or if you can chat to the developers so you can be sure that they are all likely to keep on sharing the same values, then I say go ahead and do it. Bear in mind that future apps deployed onto the server would also have access to those settings, so if you if you can't trust them, and if the setting values are confidential, you may want to keep those separate still.